# Firebase Child Elements in Database Order

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am uploading an image to `firebase` storage and then pushing name and `url` of that image in database and then i am retrieving the image `url` to display the image in my `recyclerview`. Now i want to display the newest image uploaded to firebase storage at the start of `recyclerview`,so how can i change the order in my `Firebase` Database.Right now,the first image you add is the first image in database.I want the latest image which user uploads,that image's `url` should be at the top of `firebase` database.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

firebase returns results in ascending order even if sorted. What you can do is use `Query` with `orderByKey() or orderByChild()` and `limitToLast()`, it will still give you ascending items but like last elements which you can then manually sort to show latest item

Comment: how to add query to this code mMessagesDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                contactList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Photos imageUploadInfo = postSnapshot.getValue(Photos.class);
                    if(!contactList.contains(imageUploadInfo)){
                        contactList.add(imageUploadInfo);
                        Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: "+contactList);
}}